# `ssh -NfR` equivalent with dropbear

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, openwrt, embedded, dropbear

I want to open a reverse tunnel in background. When using OpenSSH `ssh -NfR 9022:127.0.0.1:22 <target>` always worked. When I did that with dropbear on my router, it failed like this:

```
# ssh -NfR 9022:127.0.0.1:22 <target>
ssh: Exited: Error resolving '9022:localhost:22' port '22'. Name or service not known
```

ssh -R works fine, but doesn't start in background. Leaving either 'f' or 'R' didn't help; it printed the same error. Replacing the `127.0.0.1` with `localhost` didn't help either.

Please, SF, help me! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dropbear does not support the short form of options, try this instead:

```
ssh -N -f -R 9022:127.0.0.1:22 <target>
```

Comment: Damn, I should've tried that. I'll do it as soon as I have access again (about 22:00+01)